# FileOutputStream, directory

Tags: java, sockets

this is my directory structure

[image: Directory Structure in IntelliJ]

Inside the server I have the following code for saving a file that gets sent from the client

```
fileName = reader.readLine();
                    DataInputStream dis = null;
                    try {
                        dis = new DataInputStream(csocket.getInputStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                        buffer = new byte[4096];

                        int fileSize = 15123;
                        int read = 0;
                        int totalRead = 0;
                        int remaining = fileSize;
                        while((read = dis.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(buffer.length, remaining))) > 0) {
                            totalRead += read;
                            remaining -= read;
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }

                        fos.close();
                        dis.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                    break;
```

I'm wondering how I would go about saving the file within the xml folder? I've tried using getClass().getResource and such but nothing seems to work.

fileName is just a simple string containing the name of the file, not a path or anything.

I get the correct path using this code:

```
File targetDir = new File(getClass().getResource("xml").getPath());
                        File targetFile = new File(targetDir, fileName);
                        targetFile.createNewFile();

                        System.out.println(targetFile.getAbsolutePath());

                        dis = new DataInputStream(csocket.getInputStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFile.getAbsolutePath(), false);
```

But it still won't save it there...

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to receive explicitly the target path for storing files, either through a `.properties` file or a command-line argument. In this way, you make your program flexible to be installed and adapted in different environments.

But if you wish your program to assume the target directory automatically, the best option is to set a relative path before creating the FileOutputStream, as long as you start your program always from the same path:

```
File targetDir=new File("xml");
File targetFile=new File(targetDir, fileName);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
```

This will work assuming the program is started from `server` as current directory.

### Update

Other minor suggestions about your program:

1. Never base the exit condition of the loop on a hard-coded file size, because it is not possible to know it `a priori`. Instead, check explicitly if the value returned by `read` is less than 0 => that means End Of File reached.
2. Consequently, do not bother to calculate the exact amount of data to get through a call to `read`. Just enter the buffer size, because you are setting a *maximum* data size.
3. Never let exceptions catched without a proper treatment: If you know how to make your program recover, enter a proper code into the catch block. Otherwise, you'd better not catch them: Declare them in the `throws` clause and let them be propagated to the caller.
4. Always create stream resources through the `try-with-resources` instruction, to ensure they got closed at the end:

   try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(...))
   {
       // ... use fos...
   }
5. Save unnecessary instructions: If you don't care about if the file already exists on the filesystem or not, don't call `createNewFile`. But if you care, check the returned value and bifurcate consequently.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work :/ The program is the server indeed, so it is started from the server file.

Comment: "From the server file"? What do you mean? Isn't it started from the "server" directory, as I supposed?

Comment: You are correct, I've actually managed to get the correct folder path but it just doesn't want to save the file there.

Comment: Updating main post

Comment: "But it still won't save it there"? Explain exactly what is happening now, please.

Comment: The System.out prints the correct path. But the file still wont get saved in the location. The function is used to save a file that gets sent from a client. The file doesn't even show up anywhere and the client just terminates and the server just keeps rolling without any error messages. Not even an empty file is created in the location.

Comment: I suspect an IOException is ocurring, but your program is swallowing them silently. I've updated my answer. Take a look at it.

Comment: Yeah something is totally wrong, if I print the contents of the directory the files are there, but I can't see them, not even in the file explorer. What could cause this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163588/discussion-between-little-santi-and-lithicas).

Answer (score 0):

I try to create file and it does created but not at ProjectName\src\com\company\xml but in ProjectName\out\production\ProjectName\com\company\xml
my code:

```
 File targetDir = new File(this.getClass().getResource("xml").getPath());
 // get the parent of the file
 String parentPath = targetDir.getParent( );
 String fileName="xml/name.txt";
 //do something
 File targetFile = new File(parentPath, fileName);
 targetFile.createNewFile();
```

Just pay attention that after compilation you will try to save it into a jar file and it a complicated thing to do.
usually you need to save file into file outside from your jar(separate in the root) like this:[image]